# Setting NSSpeechSynthesizer mode from Python

Tags: python, objective-c, text-to-speech, appkit, nsspeechsynthesizer

I am using PyObjC bindings to try to get a spoken sound file from phonemes.

I figured out that I can turn speech into sound as follows:

```
import AppKit
ss = AppKit.NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().init()
ss.setVoice_('com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex')
ss.startSpeakingString_toURL_("Hello", AppKit.NSURL.fileURLWithPath_("hello.aiff"))
# then wait until ve.isSpeaking() returns False
```

Next for greater control I'd like to turn the text first into phonemes, and then speak them.

```
phonemes = ss.phonemesFromText_("Hello")
```

But now I'm stuck, because I know from the docs that to get `startSpeakingString` to accept phonemes as input, you first need to set NSSpeechSynthesizer.SpeechPropertyKey.Mode to "phoneme". And I think I'm supposed to use `setObject_forProperty_error_` to set that.

There are two things I don't understand:

- **Where is `NSSpeechSynthesizer.SpeechPropertyKey.Mode` in PyObjC?** I grepped the entire PyObjC directory and `SpeechPropertyKey` is not mentioned anywhere.
- **How do I use `setObject_forProperty_error_` to set it?** I think based on [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer/1448425-setobject?language=objc) that the first argument is the value to set (although it's called just "an object", so True in this case?), and the second is the key (would be phoneme in this case?), and finally there is an error callback. But I'm not sure how I'd pass those arguments in Python.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is NSSpeechSynthesizer.SpeechPropertyKey.Mode in PyObjC?

Nowhere.

> How do I use setObject_forProperty_error_ to set it?

```
ss.setObject_forProperty_error_("PHON", "inpt", None)
```

"PHON" is the same as NSSpeechSynthesizer.SpeechPropertyKey.Mode.phoneme
"inpt" is the same as NSSpeechSynthesizer.SpeechPropertyKey.inputMode

It seems these are not defined anywhere in PyObjC, but I found them by firing up XCode and writing a short Swift snippet:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

let synth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
let x = NSSpeechSynthesizer.SpeechPropertyKey.Mode.phoneme
let y = NSSpeechSynthesizer.SpeechPropertyKey.inputMode
```

Now looking at x and y in the debugger show that they are the strings mentioned above.

As for how to call setObject_forProperty_error_, I simply tried passing in those strings and None as the error handler, and that worked.